# simulation in R: reading arrival times and service times from a set and have priority queue

Tags: r, simulation, queueing, interarrival-time

I want to simulate an outpatient clinic that does not have walk-in. based on a scheduling model, I have already calculated arrival times and examination times and whether the patient will be a show or a no-show:
[image]

We have a decipline or priority rule. let me show it by an example:

Suppose at 9:30AM patient4 (which is the 4th booked patient) arrives. patient4 is scheduled for 10:15AM. according to our decipline, patient 4 can enter the queue to get visited only if patient3 which is booked for 9:50AM is either already in the queue or started the visit or has finished it. so if patient3 gonna be a no-show then patient4 have to wait till 9:50AM and then can enter the queue.

We want to simulate the patients based on this decipline and read the data from the dataset that we already have.

How can I do this simulation in R? what other solution/tools do you suggest?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What's the objective / point of this?

Comment: Check out the simmer package. I think this is possible but you’ll need to write custom functions for the arrival and seizing actions. Simmer will allow you to provide for instance exact arrival times or a distribution it can select from randomly. In this case you would need a function that has the scheduled time with some random variations and feed those as the arrivals into the simulation. The part about waiting to enter the queue until 9:50 is not something I’ve done in an equivalent manner.